# Possible way to write a > 0 ? -1 : 1 in a different way?

Tags: java

Is it possible to rewrite this code in any different way? Using bitwise operators or something similar.

`return a > 0 ? -1 : 1;`

Comment: Why does the length of this code matter? Are you strapped for characters (ie golfing)?

Comment: You *are* using logic operators.

Comment: Possibly more appropriate for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> different way [...] using bitwise operators

Definitely possible

```
return ((a * -1) >>> 31) * -2 + 1;
```

It's not pretty or clear, **I would not recommend using this**

*Also note that this will break for a=-2147483648 (the largest negative value negated equals itself)*

---

This works because the first bit will be 1 for negative numbers, and 0 for non-negative

Issue is, you want positive and non-positive, so we negate by multiplying by -1

Once we have that sorted out, shifting the first bit to the last bit will return 0/1, for a being non-positive/positive

Multiplying this by -2 will give the range you desired (1 to -1), but will leave it at 0 to -2

To fix this, add 1

---

As MFisherKDX pointed out in the comments, the multiply could be replaced by a bit shift

But since we just shifted right, shifting left is counter productive, so we can just shift right by one bit less

```
return 1 - (a * -1 >>> 30 & 2);
```

Comment: could you provide a couple of comments for your code? it would be awesome

Comment: @rocknow Was writing it up, just making sure the code works

Comment: you could replace the multiply with a shift

Comment: @MFisherKDX True, but leaving it as a multiply leaves it open for other outputs (ie return -50 and 6).  But in light of that, a different solution comes to mind